# making columns inside a main column with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have made the below image in Bootstrap 3. I am programming for a site there is using BS3. There is no possibility to use BS4.

I am having so many problems with the column height with BS3, so I am giving up now. I started working with flexboxes last week, because it seems so much easier to work with.

[image]

Is it possible to make the design lige on the image with flexboxes? I have made the 2 main columns with flexboxes, but I am not quite sure how to make the 2 columns inside the right main column. I tried to fit some bootstrap in it, but that went totally wrong.

```css
.call-out-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    }
    .call-out {
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        flex-basis: 48%;
    }
    .call-out:nth-child(1) {background-color: pink}
    .call-out:nth-child(2) {background-color:rgb(41, 255, 201)}

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .call-out-container {
            display:flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="call-out-container">
    <div class="call-out">
        <h4>Headline 1</h4>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="call-out">
        <h4>Headline 2</h4><hr/>
        
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want the two `call-out` elements next to each other. Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.call-out` elements. The problem is that padding is calculated on top of the width, unless you change how the box-sizing property is applied. Adding `border-box` calculates the padding as part of the width of the element.

Comment: you want to create design like second image ?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. @aviboy2006: Yes correct, I need to design the 2 columns like on the image I posted. But I am pretty much stuck I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create the design on the right using flexbox, you need to:

**1. Take your two columns and wrap them into a separate div.**

```
   <div class="call-out">
            <h4>Headline 2</h4><hr/>
            <div class="two-column">
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150.png">
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150.png">
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

In this example I wraped the two columns into a div called *two column*

**2. Display Flex the newly created div**

```
.two-column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

**[You can see the result here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7tJl.png)**

**Please Note:** You will have to add some adjustments/media-queries to give your desired responsive behavior, however this approach should easily allow you to create your nested-column layout.

**Helpful Note:** Remember you can always display: flex elements that are children on elements that are already using display: flex

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. As you wrote I can see there needs some viewport. I can see the images are going over the column on small devices. Can you give me a hint were to start on the viewport? I am totally new to flexbox, so I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I would recommend collapsing the 2-column design into 1 column for mobile view-- this is pretty common. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/motanveer/dLo0mg31/25/

Comment: Hey again @motantan. Thank you for your time. What I am really in doubt about is how to make the columns not go together: https://ibb.co/K70YVLM. I would like there is still a space between the columns when you resize the windows. At the moment they float together. How would that be possible?

Comment: I would generally recommend just using margin for that. ```.two-colum > div{margin:10px}``` and the same thing for ```.call-out``` should do the trick.